# SQL Server Query helper

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have two tables as follow,  I want to write a query and the rule is
I want to find out which orderID DOES NOT have attachmentID.
How can I query it in SQL?

```
OrderID      Name
1              Computer      
2              Laptop      
3              Tablet      

AttachmentID      OrderID      Url
1                       1      ….
2                       2      ….
```

Comment: So you are looking for `OrderID = 3`? That's the job of a `LEFT JOIN` looking for `AttachmentID IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    Orders o
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Attachments a
        where   a.OrderID = o.OrderID
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer, assuming Sql Server

```
select OrderID from Orders
EXCEPT
select OrderID from Attachments
```

See [MSDN doc for Except and Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) for more info.